# How to color unused NSTableRowView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, cocoa

I know how to change the background-color a row with data, using rowViewForRow() or didAddRowView(), but how to color all the rows in a NSTableView with more rows than data?

Here's a picture of my brilliant app, there is one row with text "ab", it's green (for now). The rest are grey or white - how do I change those?

[image]

Also, where did that gear icon come from?! I didn't put it there :/

Comment: how are you displaying data in your table?  are you using bindings or are you using [`tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDataSource/tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:) (i.e. NSTableViewDataSource methods) or are you using something else?

Comment: I'm using viewForTableColumn, so NSTableViewDataSource methods.